# Ondulatory routing in Raspberry Pi

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, signal, routing

I bought a Raspberry Pi and I noticed some of the routings are not straight lines but instead they make a funny ondulatory shape (see picture at the right and bottom of the processor).

I'm not sure the reason of this shape. I have two guesses:

- It makes this signals slightly delayed compared to others.
- It makes the the route a certain exact length which would avoid resonance frequencies.

Are my guesses correct? Or this shapes are for something else?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct, these meanders are used to get exact timings of the signals. It is necessary to match differential pairs with high speed signals.